# Append element underneath the element that was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on getting a text field to appear underneath the element that was changed. When the user checks the check box I want the text field to display below the check box and push all the elements down. How do I accomplish this? Right now it just adds the text box at the bottom of the div. I have included a fiddle [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/VVp8t/)

This is the code I use to add the text field:

```
function displayDate(dateBox) {
    if($('#' + dateBox + "Date").length) {
        $( '#' + dateBox + "Date" ).remove();
    } else {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.id = dateBox + "Date";
        input.name = dateBox + "Date";
        document.getElementById("displayingDealers").appendChild(input);
    }

}
```

Here is the container:

```
<fieldset class="wideFieldSet">
    <div id="displayingDealers">
    <legend>Displaying Dealer Details</legend>      
        <p>What products do you have on display?</p>
        <p><label class="wideLabel" for="93057">93057</label><input class="floatLeftCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="93057" name="displayingdealerdetails[93057]" onchange="displayDate(this.id)"/></p>
        <p><label class="wideLabel" for="93058">93058</label><input class="floatLeftCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="93058" name="displayingdealerdetails[93058]" onchange="displayDate(this.id)" /></p>
        <p><label class="wideLabel" for="93107">93107</label><input class="floatLeftCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="93107" name="displayingdealerdetails[93107]" onchange="displayDate(this.id)" /></p>
        <p><label class="wideLabel" for="93108">93108</label><input class="floatLeftCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="93108" name="displayingdealerdetails[93108]" onchange="displayDate(this.id)" /></p>
        <p><label class="wideLabel" for="93117">9311</label><input class="floatLeftCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="93117" name="displayingdealerdetails[93117]" onchange="displayDate(this.id)"/></p>
        <p><label class="wideLabel" for="93118">93118</label><input class="floatLeftCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="93118" name="displayingdealerdetails[93118]" onchange="displayDate(this.id)" /></p>
        <p><label class="wideLabel" for="93085">93085</label><input class="floatLeftCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="93085" name="displayingdealerdetails[93085]" onchange="displayDate(this.id)"/></p>
        <p><label class="wideLabel" for="EOH51294">EOH51294</label><input class="floatLeftCheckbox" type="checkbox" id="EOH51294" name="displayingdealerdetails[EOH51294]" onchange="displayDate(this.id)" /></p>

        <p><label for="OtherText">If other please explain</label><input type="text" name="displayingdealerdetails[OtherText]" id="OtherText" /></p>

        <p class="navigation"><button class="button" type="button" onclick="prevForm();">Previous</button>                                                                                              
                              <button class="button" type="button" onclick="nextForm();">Next</button></p>

    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Why would this get down voted there is code and even a fiddle. The question is legitimate

Comment: To be fair, this isn't *technically* a question (but I'd agree, doesn't warrant the downvotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append the textbox to each paragraph. Here is a modified version of the JS code:

```
function displayDate(dateBox) {
    if($('#' + dateBox + "Date").length) {
        $( '#' + dateBox + "Date" ).remove();
    } else {
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.type = "text";
        input.id = dateBox + "Date";
        input.name = dateBox + "Date";
        $('#'+dateBox).parent().append(input);
    }

}
```

Also I have an updated fiddle : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bobby5193/VVp8t/1/)

Comment: Thank you! How would I add a label before the text box that says "Date purchased"

Answer (score 1):

[`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) and [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) can both achieve what you're looking for. The only difference is their syntax:

```
$("<p>Test</p>").insertAfter(".inner");
$(".inner").after("<p>Test</p>");
// Both of the above lines do the same thing; you would use one, not both
...
<div class="container">
    <h2>Greetings</h2>
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
    <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

Result:

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>Greetings</h2>
    <div class="inner">Hello</div>
    <p>Test</p>
    <div class="inner">Goodbye</div>
    <p>Test</p>
</div>
```